# A program which converts base 10 number into other given numbering system

Tags: java, numbers, hex

The task is to build a program in Java which where the user enter a base 10 number and when the selected numbering system is base 16, the program should replace the remainder numbers 10,11,12 by A,B and C respectively.

The part where I don’t understand is how to make the program replace the remainder number to letters.

Comment: To begin, think about how you would go about doing this methodically on paper. Start with a base 10 number and think about what steps you would take to convert it to base 16.

Comment: You will need to treat it as a string. The string can contain characters {0,1,2,3,...,9,A,B,...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that would do that. Since A, B, C are in order in ASCII table, you can use it for your advantage:

```
    char c = 'A';
    int charValue = number;
    if (number > 9) charValue = (number - 10) + (int) c; 
    System.out.println((char) charValue);
```

So you take number, substract 10, add int value of first character 10 (so 10 will be A, 11 will be B, etc). This would be a basic idea for one reminder, full code depends on your logic for input (does it comes as string? would be better since you will end up with string, etc).